# Relabeling in Promtheus not working as expected

Tags: regex, prometheus

I am fetching the cloudwatch metrics using the cloudwatch exporter, trying to relabel the target_group to "/servicename/ping", Please find the metrics fetched on the prometheus shown below:

aws_applicationelb_httpcode_target_5_xx_count_sum{availability_zone="us-east-1d",exported_job="aws_applicationelb",instance="ops-prometheus-server-1.com:9106",job="Devops-cloudwatch-exporter",load_balancer="app/ALB-Appli-NQBSSAHW/66b59123ed13c6e",target_group="targetgroup/Micro-ALBTa-K3SKWNESS7M/aasdasfcef66af3"}

Please find the lines from the prometheus.yml file entry for the same given below:

```
  - source_labels: [target_group]
    regex: '.*Micro-ALBTa-K3SKWNESS7M.*'
    replacement: '/servicename/ping'
    target_label: target_group
```

This is not working as expected, can you anyone help me on this, let me know if i am missing anything in the configuration.

Thanks
Sreejith

Answer (score 0):

target_group here is coming from the cloudwatch exporter rather than service discovery, so you should use `metric_relabel_configs` rather than `relabel_configs`.

Comment: I have made the changes as you have mentioned, but still didnt work, please find the entry made in prometheus.yml file given below:

    metric_relabel_configs:
       - source_labels: [target_group]
         regex: '.*Micro-ALBTa-K3SKWNESS7M.*'
         replacement: '/servicename/ping'
         target_label: target_group

Comment: I have multiple source labels need to be replaced so the configuration file has multiple entries under metric_relabel_configs, but i can see only one entry under metric_relabel_configs from Prometheus UI which is the last entry in the configuration file, is this might be the reason other relabel not working

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue with the formate of the metric_relabel_configs in the configuration file. For multiple relable i made my configuration as show below:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [target_group]
    regex: '.*Micro-ALBTa-K3SKWNESS7M.*'
    replacement: '/servicename/ping'
    target_label: target_group

  - source_labels: [target_group]
    regex: '.*Micro1-ALBTa-1DIK3W2TWKXG7.*'
    replacement: Micro1
    target_label: target_group
```

Hence fixed